# In javascript, can I create a sort function that puts the top 10 count on top, sorted by alphabet?

Tags: javascript, sorting, sortcomparefunction

I have a set of colours and the number of products found in that colour:

```
[
  {colour: 'red', count: 100},
  {colour: 'green', count: 30},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 80},
  ...
]
```

The list is much longer than this. I want:

- to show the top ten colours with the highest count on top of the list,
- but sort that top 10 by alphabet.

I can only use a js compareFunction, once. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

Supplemental, I'm trying to get this sorting result in using the [refinementList](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#refinementlist) of the Algolia InstantSearch library. As documented, the sortBy can only take a single sorting function. If anyone has a different solution for that then that would of course also suffice.

I'm rather surprised by the eagerness of people to provide answers that don't fit the requirements. Regardless of the use case, this seems to me like an interesting problem to actually find a solution to.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you asked your tutor for help?

Comment: You can first sort by count and then sort the top 10 alphabetically, both using simple custom sorts... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Archer I cannot, because, as clearly stated in the question, I can only call a compareFunction once.

Comment: Please explain why you can only call it once.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I haven't tried anything, I simply can't come up with a possible solution for this. For as far as having a "tutor" goes, I have a manager who requested this logic from me, the issue has been discussed, ofcourse.

Comment: @Archer I'm passing it as the argument for the the sortBy property of the refinementList of the Algolia Instant Search widget. https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#refinementlist

Comment: In that case you're not going to get what you're asking for.  This requirement *needs* to do 2 different sorts.

Answer (score 3):

This will sort *regardless* of the count *after* determining the top 'n' records.  So, ordered by descending order it will then re-sort on this sliced array using the second dynamic array object property `colour` to order alphabetically:

```js
// example array:
const arr = [
    {colour: 'blue', count: 10},
    {colour: 'red', count: 100},
    {colour: 'red', count: 101},
    {colour: 'green', count: 30},
    {colour: 'green', count: 40},
    {colour: 'blue', count: 100},
    {colour: 'white', count: 40},
    {colour: 'orange', count: 40}
];

// multiple sort function:
const orderedCollection = (arr, n, ...props) => {
  return arr
   // create a copy of the array
   .slice(0)
        // sort by descending order i.e "count"
        .sort((a, b) => b[props[0]] - a[props[0]])
        // take 'n' number of records i.e 5
        .slice(0, n)
        // sort alphabetically (a-z), based on property i.e "colour"
        .sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[props[1]] < b[props[1]]) return -1;
        if (a[props[1]] > b[props[1]]) return 1;
        return 0;
     });
};

// top 5, using props count & colour.
orderedCollection(arr, 5, "count", "colour")
 .forEach((obj, index) => { 
           // example output:
           console.log(`${index +1}. ${obj.colour} - ${obj.count}`);
         });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm after, I want the top 10 to be alphabetic, regardless of their count.

Comment: @JasperKennis okay, that wasn't in the original question. Perhaps an output from a sample set of data would have been more helpful.

In this scenario, two individual sorts are required.

Comment: @JasperKennis I have updated my answer with a clearer explanation wrapped into a single function.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 : Use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method**

sorting the Array elements(objects) by their count (descending). Here's the comparison function that does this **:**

```
var sortByCount = jsonObj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
});
```

Here, `jsonObj` is the source array of objects which is `unsorted`.

**Step 2 : Use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get top 10 records from the sorted array**

**Syntax :** `array.slice(start, end)`

```
var sortByCount = jsonObj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
});

var topTen = sortByCount.slice(0,10);
```

**Step 3 : Again sort the top 10 records based on the alphabet in ascending order.**

```
var sortByCount = jsonObj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
});

var topTen = sortByCount.slice(0,10);

var sortByName = topTen.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.colour < b.colour) return -1;
    if(a.colour > b.colour) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = [
  {colour: 'red', count: 100},
  {colour: 'green', count: 30},
  {colour: 'zlue', count: 40},
  {colour: 'dlue', count: 90},
  {colour: 'ylue', count: 20},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 25},
  {colour: 'jlue', count: 45},
  {colour: 'klue', count: 2556},
  {colour: 'slue', count: 46},
  {colour: 'xlue', count: 745},
  {colour: 'qlue', count: 76},
  {colour: 'tlue', count: 65}
];

var sortByCount = jsonObj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
});

var topTen = sortByCount.slice(0,10);

var sortByName = topTen.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.colour < b.colour) return -1;
    if(a.colour > b.colour) return 1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(sortByName);
```

Comment: *"I can only use a js compareFunction, once."*

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
  {colour: 'red', count: 100},
  {colour: 'green', count: 30},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 80},
  {colour: 'red', count: 17},
  {colour: 'green', count: 50},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 8},
  {colour: 'red', count: 16},
  {colour: 'green', count: 45},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 35},
  {colour: 'red', count: 15},
  {colour: 'green', count: 25},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 20},
  {colour: 'red', count: 10},
  {colour: 'green', count: 40},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 70}
]
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return  b['count'] - a['count'];
})
arr.splice(10)
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.colour.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.colour.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }
// names must be equal
  return 0;
});
console.log(arr);
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/7yhwc3e1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a two pass style, for getting first the top values and the order the array be top value and by alphabet.

The result contains all items, the ten top items in the first part ordered by `name` and the rest is also ordered by name, but not first.

```js
var data = [{ colour: 'red', count: 100 }, { colour: 'green', count: 30 }, { colour: 'blue', count: 80 }, { colour: 'white', count: 40 }, { colour: 'black', count: 5 }, { colour: 'pink', count: 8 }, { colour: 'yellow', count: 99 }, { colour: 'cyan', count: 37 }, { colour: 'magenta', count: 32 }, { colour: 'grey', count: 23 }, { colour: 'mint', count: 13 }, { colour: 'brown', count: 18 }, { colour: 'orange', count: 1 }, { colour: 'x', count: 0 }, { colour: 'b', count: -1 }, { colour: 'a', count: -2 }, { colour: 'y', count: -4 }],
    count = data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var min;
        if (r.length < 10) {
            return r.concat(a.count);
        }
        min = Math.min(...r);
        if (a.count > min) {
            r[r.indexOf(min)] = a.count;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return count.includes(b.count) - count.includes(a.count) || a.colour.localeCompare(b.colour);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This assumes I can do something else do data, but I cannot, I can only pass a single sort function. I might, however, be able to incorporate the reduce in the sort method. I'll try this.

Comment: no, that does not work, because you need to get all counts in advance. inside of the callback, you get only two counts and has no access to the other items, even if you think, you could build the count array on the run. the earlier sorted items remain on the place they have. there is no final sort run to cover orphan or rest parts.

Comment: but if you have a data base, you could do a sub select with an aggregate function.

Comment: The data changes all the time, depending on some other filters; if you change the price range you want to search in, the remaining colours/products set is different.

Comment: i suggest to sort by count and then by presenting the data sort it by alphabet. you could use a onload event or another suitable event for a local sort of the output part.

Answer (score 0):

this should provide some insight in how you can sort custom arrays.
if you swap a and b around you'll sort into the opposite direction.

yes i'm aware you said you'd only want to use one compare function call but honestly..
if a prof is forcing you to do so, you might want to consider switching courses or make him realize his idiology is dumb for practical use.

after all, stackoverflow is not made to answer questions that have no relation to unefficient usecases.

```js
[
  {colour: 'red', count: 100},
  {colour: 'green', count: 30},
  {colour: 'blue', count: 80},
  {colour: 'pink', count: 1337},
  {colour: 'black', count: 10},
  {colour: 'orange', count: 101}
]
// sort by count
.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
// extract first three colours
.splice(0, 3)
// sort by text
.sort((a, b) => a.colour > b.colour ? 1 : a.colour < b.colour ? -1 : 0)
// print the result into the console
.forEach((x, i) => console.log(`${['first', 'second', 'third'][i]}: ${x.colour}`));
```

Comment: I think it's because the output doesn't match what OP is asking for, as `pink` should be first.

Comment: @evolutionxbox abcdefghijklmn O P q R stuvwxyz. clearly orange → pink → red.

Comment: Ah right. Find "top ten", then sort alphabetically.

Comment: @evolutionxbox you really expect me to throw 10+ colors into the array and do that? since i'm not going to do his homework all i did was throwing in a valid alternative solution to his problem.

Answer (score -1):

For that first, you need to use array sort function on count(numbers) and then on color(Text). To fetch the top data, you can use array slice. Just refer the basic JavaScript functions and try yourself.
See below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var colorsarray = [
                            {colour: 'red', count: 100},
                            {colour: 'green', count: 30},
                            {colour: 'blue', count: 80},
                            {colour: 'yellow', count: 60},
                            {colour: 'purple', count: 50},
                            {colour: 'pink', count: 10},
                            {colour: 'brown', count: 90},
                            {colour: 'black', count: 70},
                            {colour: 'white', count: 20},
                            {colour: 'gold', count: 110},
                            {colour: 'silver', count: 150},
                            {colour: 'orange', count: 130},
                            {colour: 'grey', count: 40},
        ];

        colorsarray.sort(function(a, b){
            return a.count-b.count
        });

        colorsarray.sort(function(a, b){
            var name1=a.colour.toLowerCase(), 
            var name2=b.colour.toLowerCase(),
            if (name1 < name2)
                return -1 
            if (name1 > name2)
                return 1
            return 0
        });

        console.log(colorsarray.slice(1,10));
    </script>
```

Comment: This is the same answer as has been given several times before, and it doesn't comply with the required functionality of being a single sort function.